# import pyHook failed

Tags: python-2.7, pyhook

I Have installed pyHook for my windows 64 bit.The setup has installed it in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages dir i cant import pyhook (i can see win32 named folder there think so it is its folder) in my code what should i do 
Here is interpreters output

```
>>> import pyHook

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyHook
ImportError: No module named pyHook
>>> import pyhook

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyhook
ImportError: No module named pyhook
>>>
```

Comment: What does `import sys` and then `sys.path` tell you? Is C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages listed there?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\
\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27
', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32'
, 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packa
ges\\Pythonwin']
>>>
Yes there is

Comment: How did you install pyHook on 64-bit Python? It seems the latest build has 32-bit only installers: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/pyhook/1.5.1/ Did you get it from another source?

Comment: For pure Python I would recommend `hooked`: https://github.com/IronManMark20/pyhooked It's for keyboard hooks only. But you don't need any binaries like .pyd files in pyHook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all win32 is not the pyHook module it is an other module.

Here is how to install pyHook:

1.You can find the download link here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

2.If you have python 32bit you want pyhook 32 bit (Download #1 for Python 2.7).

3.If you have python 64bit you want pyHook 64 bit (Download #2 for Python 2.7).

4.Extract the zip file.

5.In the command prompt navigate to the folder where you extracted the .zip.

6.Type the command 'pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl' for the 32 bit version
or 'pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl'

Good Luck!